MKDIR criar Diretório em Maiúsculas
Através desse batch script cria as pastas e move os arquivos diferenciando as extensões
tendo arquivo(s) .tXt no diretório cria a pasta .tXt e move o(s) arquivo(s) .tXt para lá.
Entretanto as pastas criadas são conformes as extensões pré nomeadas como estão maiúsculas/minúsculas
Como criar essas pastas em UPPERCASE?
Nomeando(as) todas em maiúsculas?
@echo off

for %%a in (".\*") do (
      if "%%~xa" NEQ "" if "%%~dpxa" NEQ "%~dpx0" (
            if not exist "%%~xa" mkdir "%%~xa" (
                   move "%%a" "%%~dpa%%~xa\"
            )
       )
)


Olá amigo veja se é isso no caso é usado powershell dentro de um bat para transformar as letras em maúsculo:
@echo off

for %%a in (".\*") do IF NOT [%%~xa]==[%~x0] IF NOT [%%~xa]==[] call :MoverArquivo "%%~a"
exit

:MoverArquivo
echo "%~1"
IF NOT EXIST "%~x1\" powershell -command "new-item -itemtype Directory ((get-childitem '%~1').extension.ToUpper())|out-null"
move "%~1" "%~x1"
GOTO :EOF

https://i.imgur.com/bLeXgdE.gif

é isso sim.. muito grato obrigado

Amigo olá novamente, percebe-se que ao mover arquivo de mesmo nome dentro da pasta da extensáo desse arquivo de nome igual lá presente é substutito pelo arquivo mais novo. Melhor seria renomear mantendo os dois arquivos invés de substituir.. Saberia o desenvolver? Náo obtive exitos em tentativas..
